# Ubuntu 22.04 mouse and keyboard lags alot

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 22.04

After upgrading to `Ubuntu 22.04` I have many performance issues. One of them which is too annoying is that after some time, ubuntu gets lagfull. mouse stop working in periods for two or three seconds, keyboard suddenly repeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaate a key(when I was writing this issue you can see that it occurs again).
`htop` says that I just use 9.5Gb Ram of 16GB, Load average is 0.9 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand (again it occurs) CPU usage is at its minimum possible value.
I also add `intel_iommu=off` to my grub configs:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"`

but it does not work.

Comment: Did you use an external graphics card? I faced this issue on 18.04 using nvidia GPU. Mostly it is related to GPU, in my case.

Comment: My laptop has a GPU but, when I checked the additional drivers in ubuntu settings, it says that I'm using X.Org as a display driver. Should I check anything else? @sugab

Comment: For my case, I left it as it is since I just use it via ssh. Using x.org may be the culprit. If your laptop has an Nvidia graphic, you should install the proprietary driver for smoothness. If it doesn't resolve the problem, I will try first via live USB, and then fresh install 22.04 if the problem doesn't appear on live USB.

Comment: I have this same issue, although mine seems to result in lost characters and slow/lost mouse movement, BUT, I don't have a graphics card, just using onboard Intel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time search, I figured out that changing additional drivers from `x.org` to a `proprietary driver` would fix the issue.

Comment: Kind of hard to use proprietary drivers for logitech for example